# Kafka Streams local state stores

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a simple streams application takes one topic as input stream and transforms KeyValues to another like:

```
StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<Long, CategoryDto>> builder =
        Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(CategoryTransformer.STORE_NAME),
                                    Serdes.Long(), CATEGORY_JSON_SERDE);
    streamsBuilder.addStateStore(builder)
                         .stream(categoryTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.Long(), CATEGORY_JSON_SERDE))
                         .transform(CategoryTransformer::new, CategoryTransformer.STORE_NAME);

static class CategoryTransformer implements Transformer<Long, CategoryDto, KeyValue<Long, CategoryDto>> {

    static final String STORE_NAME = "test-store";

    private KeyValueStore<Long, CategoryDto> store;

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
      store = (KeyValueStore<Long, CategoryDto>) context.getStateStore(STORE_NAME);
    }

    @Override
    public KeyValue<Long, CategoryDto> transform(Long key, CategoryDto value) {
      store.put(key, value);
      return KeyValue.pair(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public KeyValue<Long, CategoryDto> punctuate(long timestamp) {
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
  }
```

Here i had to use transformer because i need to fetch store and update relevant value.

The question is what is the difference between using local state stores, and just putting values to a simple `HashMap` inside a `ForeachAction`?

What is the advantage of using local state stores in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it is not shown in your code, I'm assuming you somehow read and use the stored state.

Storing your state using a simple (in memory) `HashMap` makes your state not persistent at all, this means your state will be lost when either of the following happens (those are nothing out of the ordinary, assume it will happen quite often):

- your stream processor/applications stops,
- crashes, or
- is partially migrated elsewhere (other JVM) due to rebalancing.

The problem with a non-persistent state is that when any of the above happens, kafka-streams will restart the processing at the last committed offset. As such all records processed before the crash/stop/rebalance will not be reprocessed, this means the content of your `HashMap` will be empty when the processing restarts. This is certainly not what you want.

On the other hand, if you use one of the provided state stores, kafka-streams will ensure that, once the processing restarts after any of the interruptions listed above, the state will be available as if the processing never stopped, without reprocessing any of the previously processed records.

Comment: If I were to use `log compaction` and begin processing topic with earliest offset when application (re)starts, are those 3 cases handled?

Comment: topics backing state stores (so called changelog topics) should not need any special setting, they use log compaction. Are you talking about the `auto.offset.reset` config? This is useful only if consumer offset were deleted in between, which can happen if you stopped your stream processor for more than `offsets.retention.minutes`. When offsets are deleted, I'm not sure what to tell you. But in normal cases, where you don't stop you app for more than `offsets.retention.minutes`, the 3 cases are handled just fine.

Answer (score 2):

> The question is what is the difference between using local state stores, and just putting values to a simple HashMap inside a ForeachAction?

If your input topics are not partitioned and you run a single instance of your Streams application, the value of the local state API is not huge. In such cases—sure: you can use a `HashMap` in your processors, or [some persistent `HashMap`](https://www.google.com/search?q=persistent%20hashmap%20java) if you wanted to survive restarts.

The value of local storage becomes clear when your topics are partitioned and clearer still when you run multiple instances of your Streams application. In such cases, you need to maintain specific state with the processor that's processing a specific partition, and that state needs to be able to move with the processor in case it moves to a different Streams instance. In such cases—AKA scale—the local storage facility is both necessary and invaluable. Imagine having to orchestrate this yourself at scale, vs having this facility part of the core platform (the local state API).

Comment: IMHO, fault-tolerance is the key difference and this also applies for single-partitioned topics. Btw: an In-Memory store, is basically a Java `HashMap` plus writes to a changelog topic, ie, it is a form of "persistent HashMap" is you wish.